# Convert sql date to DD/MM/YYYY with PHP

Tags: php, date

I've got an SQL server 2000 running with some data.
When I select one of my fields I get something like this:

> Sep 21 2015 12:00:00:000AM
>   Sep 14 2015 12:00:00:000AM

..etc

I would like to convert this thing to "DD/MM/YYYY".
When I'm doing a query with Access I get this format, but not with PHP.

Comment: What do you get when you query with PHP then?

Comment: Sorry was not clear, with ACCESS i get DD/MM/YYYY which is OK.
But with PHP i get Sep 21 2015 12:00:00:000AM

Comment: How do you get it with PHP? As the result of a query to a database? Which database? Table structure? Details of field containing date? PHP code?

Comment: I'm doing a simple "$query = mssql_query" to select my field 
Then i parse and do an echo.
This field in SQL2000 is datetime, size 8.

Answer (score 1):

`your query and see time and take it into a variable then fetch that index that comes with time make three array like

```
`$ar=array();

    $ar1=array();
    $ar2=array();` after it apply `$ar1[0]=$ar2[0];
    $ar1[2]=$ar[1];
    $ar1[3]=$ar[0]." ".$ar2[1];
```

then implode like

```
$dt=implode("-",$ar1);
$data[$k]['time_from']=$dt;
```

and print `$dt` you find your structure.

Comment: Wow sorry but i'm totally lost with that, i'm currently having this date format from my database "Sep 14 2015 12:00:00:000AM"
I don't even know why you are using implode with "-".
Of course i can extract the first 11 caracters, then explode with " " and rearrange everything but i'm sure that there is a more standard option to convert this format to another.

Comment: @user5115514 i just get a scenario to achieve your goal through array.you just put your date in array same time same year in array then you have three arrays.put values in array then arrange.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = '31/05/2001 12:22:56';

$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);

echo $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm under PHP 5.2 and "DateTime::createFromFormat" is for PHP 5.3